# Filters with dynamic fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am switching a very old version of ElasticSearch to version 6.5.

```
...  
  "text_mined_entities": {
            "nlp": {
                "abbreviations": [],
                "chunks": [],
                "recurring_chunks": [],
                "tagged_entities_grouped": {
                    "NEURO|SCICRUNCH": [
                        {
                            "category": "NEURO",
                            "end": 41,
                            "label": "Infant",
                            "match": "infant",
                            "original_value": "Infant",
                            "reference": "BIRNLEX695",
                            "reference_db": "SCICRUNCH",
                            "sentence": 0,
                            "start": 35
                        },
...
```

I am wanting to filter on the text_mined_entities.nlp.tagged_entities_grouped.*.reference fields ( which are stored as 'keyword' ), but haven't had much luck. Something like:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": { "term": {
        "text_mined_entities.nlp.tagged_entities_grouped.*.reference": "BIRNLEX695"

      }}

    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildcard on fields can't be applied on term query. Instead you can use query_string which supports wildcard on field as well. So following will work:

Assuming `text_mined_entities` and `nlp` are of type `nested`

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "text_mined_entities.nlp",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "BIRNLEX695",
          "fields": [
            "text_mined_entities.nlp.tagged_entities_grouped.*.reference"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update** (if `text_mined_entities` & `nlp` are `object` type and not `nested`):

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "BIRNLEX695",
      "fields": [
        "text_mined_entities.nlp.tagged_entities_grouped.*.reference"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed my mapping to be "nested" for both text_mined_entities and nlp ( they were previously "object" ) and that query works. However, would it be possible in the mapping to only index the 'reference' field? It looks like setting this as nested is causing the index size to go up quite a bit.

Comment: I have added an update with query which should work if the fields are `object` type. Regarding the possibility to index only `reference` field via mapping refer [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html). Disabling dynamic mapping might help if mapping is known and doesn't get updated too frequently.